# How to print the same iteration twice?

Tags: python, for-loop, split, counter

The prompt:
Write a program that reads a list of words. Then, the program outputs those words and their frequencies.

Ex: If the input is:

`hey hi Mark hi mark`

the output is:

```
hey 1



hi 2

Mark 1

hi 2

mark 1
```

My Code:

```
from collections import Counter
user.input = input().split()
count = counter(user_input)

for key, value in count.items():
    print('{} {}'.format(key, value))
```

I have pretty much solved the question but for some reason my output won't print out the 2nd "hi 2" as shown in the question prompt above.

Comment: print the words from the input, not from the collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate using the given sentence:

```py
from collections import Counter
user_input = input().split()
count = Counter(user_input)

for word in user_input:
    print(f'{word} {count[word]}')
```

Output:

```
hey 1
hi 2
Mark 1
hi 2
mark 1
```